# Linking Boost libraries built with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have some existing C++ source code (call it WDC source code) which I need to build into Android.  I need to eventually extend that to the APP layer, and plan on using JNI for that.  The WDC source code that I have requires the C++ Boost Libraries, not just the ones that can be included but the ones that need to be built.  My understanding is that the Boost libraries that need to be built require elements of standard C that are not included in Bionic.  MysticTreeGames has released a NDK build script to build Boost for Android (https://github.com/MysticTreeGames), which generates .a files(static linkable libraries).

My question is, can I build the WDC source code without using the NDK compiler (i.e. drop my WDC sourcecode into the 'external' folder of my OS and rebuild the OS) and link against the static libraries that were generated by the Boost Android build?  If not, do I have to build the WDC source code with NDK with 'ndk-build' and then create a JNI interface to that afterwards?

Keep in mind that for my project, I am rebuilding the OS to include this functionality and other functionality.

Thanks in advance!